# Draw Custom shapes (Geofences) zones on MKMapView

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, uibezierpath, geofencing

I'm creating an `Universal app` and I have to create custom safe zones on the `map view`.

What I do is:

1. Add a new `UIView` as superview of `map view` called `squareZone`.
2. To the `squareZone` view I add `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` so I can move, rotate and zoom (in and out).

Here is the code of SquareZone

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.765 green: 0.439 blue: 0.443 alpha: 0.658];

    UIBezierPath *rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rect];
    [color setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 5;
    CGFloat rectanglePattern[] = {2, 3};
    [rectanglePath setLineDash: rectanglePattern count: 2 phase: 0];
    [rectanglePath stroke];
}
```

[image: squareZone]

Now, when the user adjust the `squareZone` I have to show on a `UILabel` the distance between each point in meters. For that task I'm using

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

How can I add/show the four `UILabels` when the user interacts with the `squareZone`.

I need some light here. I had seen many tutorials but I cannot imagine how can this is posible. For reference, there is an app called

Trax: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trax-gps-tracker/id647170688?mt=8

I have to do the same Drawing Geofence Zone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi isaiasmac, i have seen the trax app that you referred, you want to display the distance between two points on square line's?

Comment: yes. I want to do that. I don’t know what components have the Trax app to do that effect.

Comment: have tried by using reloadInputViews function to redraw your view

Comment: I think we've done the circle version and another shape just without the color fill, could you check the screenshot in this page: https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/arko-ph/id667396845?mt=8, if that is the kind that you need?

Comment: Yes Bryan, is similar but with the difference that the shape should have Gesture attached (Pan, Pinch and Rotation).

Comment: i also want to implement same.Did you got solution for this @isaiasmac

Comment: yes, I used the answer to get the solution. You need to learn the basis of Core Graphics (https://www.raywenderlich.com/411-core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started).

Answer (score 3):

First thing to mention is that `Trax` has two different modes:

1) `editing` -- where you draw the path

2) `live` -- where it shows the result.

### Editing mode

While in `editing`, you cannot move and zoom inside of your MKMapView. This happens because they are using the same approach as you do -- they are adding a `UIView` on top of `MKMapView`, so that gestures do not conflict with each other.

All you need to do is add `CGPoint`s to some array and use them in the future.

Of course, there are a few difficulties with using `CoreGraphics` framework, but it is not that tricky.

### Live mode

After user added all `CGPoint`s, you now have to convert these points into actual `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instances.

```
CGPoint thePoint = ...
CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocationCoordinate2D = [theMapView convertPoint:thePoint toCoordinateFromView:theDrawingView];
```

What `Trax` have in their app are probably (almost certainly) instances of `MKPolygon` class.

You can add it like so:

```
NSUInteger theCount = self.theMainDrawingView.thePointsArray.count;
CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocationCoordinatesArray[theCount];
for (NSUInteger theIndex = 0; theIndex < theCount; theIndex++)
{
    CGPoint thePoint = self.theMainDrawingView.thePointsArray[theIndex].CGPointValue;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocationCoordinate2D = [self.theMainMapView convertPoint:thePoint toCoordinateFromView:self.theMainDrawingView];
    theLocationCoordinatesArray[theIndex] = theLocationCoordinate2D;
}
MKPolygon *thePolygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:theLocationCoordinatesArray count:theCount];
[self.theMainMapView addOverlay:thePolygon];
```

However, this is not the end. This will trigger a delegate method of your `MKMapView` (don't forget to set its `.delegate` property)

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPolygonView *thePolygonView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon *)overlay];
    thePolygonView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    thePolygonView.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    thePolygonView.lineWidth = 4;
    return thePolygonView;
}
```

Result looks like this:

[image: Demo CountPages alpha]

### Summary

Of course, this doesn't fully solve the issue, because you would have to add `pinch` and `pan` gestures too, but I hope that I could point into the right direction.

Comment: Is this still possible? Your sample project can't be reached anymore

Comment: @Alserda, solution still works, but the sample project doesn't exist anymore, sorry

Comment: I also want to implement same feature.Can you please share sample project.

Comment: @IosDeveloper, sorry, but the sample project doesn't exist anymore